# How to display Request.QueryString Data

Tags: asp.net

Follwing code that i have tried doesn't display any thing.

Test1.aspx

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Test2.aspx?ID=1");
}
```

Test2.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5.test2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%=Request.QueryString["ID"] %>'></asp:Label>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second page, in the codebehind file, Page_Load event, place the following code:

```
lblId.Text = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();
```

where lblId is the ID of a Label control on the second page.

Grz, Kris.

Comment: Sorry i haven't mentioned what i really need to do.What i need is ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Name","../Master Pages/DisasterImages/") %>'+'<%=Request.QueryString[\"DisID\"].ToString()/{0} %>'.ImageUrl is inside the repeater control "DisID" is the physical directory.i want to get the directory name from the QueryString.Above code doesn't work so how can i do that??? Thank You.